# How to format Ubunutu 14.04 from laptop?

Tags: laptop, format, reinstall

I only have Ubuntu os in my laptop, I want to format it and reinstall it in my Laptop. I made a bootable pd of the os, an i am using a asus laptop but the bootable window wont open. I need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://craftedflash.com/info/how-boot-computer-from-usb-flash-drive

Try to press these Boot Menu keys rapidly on booting.

[F2] for BIOS, [ESC] for boot menu (ASUS P53E)

Also please connect your bootable usb to USB 2.0 port

[image]

- Boot examples from my computer:

**Legacy Boot:**

[image: Motherboard boot menu]

[image: Ubuntu boot screen]

**UEFI Boot:**

[image: Motherboard boot menu]

[image: Ubuntu boot screen]

I have created bootable usb from this image on Windows ([How to](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)):

[image]

```
MD5(ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso)= dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153
```

**Could be the solution:** I think you are making a legacy boot. Make sure your hard disk(or ssd) listed in boot menu **immediately after** your USB drive.

- In addition, use **USB 2.0** port **not** USB 3.0

Comment: did that! does not show the bootable device

Comment: @PriyankaUppalwar Can you give me the brand name and model number of your laptop/PC

Comment: asus p53e is my laptop model

Comment: [F2] for BIOS, [ESC] for bootmenu

Comment: my usb drive was not visible in the boot menu! i have tried esc

Comment: @PriyankaUppalwar Is USB drive connected in USB 2.0? Are you sure your bootable usb is working? Can you try it on a different PC? Are you sure that you have successfully completed these steps: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: yes! I might be having some hardware problems! Thanks for the help

Comment: Input/output error! dont know how to solve that

Comment: @PriyankaUppalwar can you share the error

Comment: my laptop has only ubuntu installed, and yes i checked the usb its bootable, i used it on my pc and it worked. But from my laptop when i press esc for boot. it only shows : ubuntu, advanced option for ubuntu, and two memory tests. This is now making me crazy

Comment: @PriyankaUppalwar I updated my answer. Maybe you can share your bootscreen. Upload to [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and share the link.